# Use annotation processor generated constants indrectly in annotation will lead compile error

Tags: java, annotations, javac, annotation-processing

[Get minimize code to reproduce this](https://gist.github.com/XDean/29a225f631cefbc75752b6a35b5ccb28)

I have a `HelloWorldProcessor` who will simply generate source file `HelloWorldMessage.java`

```
public interface HelloWorldMessage { 
  String HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World";
}
```

Now I use the generated value in my code:

```
public class UseHelloWorld {
  @Anno(HelloWorldMessage.HELLO_WORLD)
  public void func(){
  }
}
```

That works fine.

But if I declared the value as constant and use it indirectly, it will cause compile error.

```
public class UseHelloWorld{
  public static final String HW =  HelloWorldMessage.HELLO_WORLD;

  @Anno(UseHelloWorld.HW)
  public void func(){
  }
}
```

Javac gives `symbol not found` error:

```
UseHelloWorld.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
  public static final String HW = HelloWorldMessage.HELLO_WORLD;
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable HelloWorldMessage
  location: class UseHelloWorld
UseHelloWorld.java:4: error: element value must be a constant expression
  @Anno(UseHelloWorld.HW)
                     ^
2 errors
```

Why I said 'javac' is because it works fine in eclipse with ECJ and m2e-apt.

Is this a javac bug? If no, how can I correct use the generated source indirectly?

Comment: Try to access to static var through class ref: @Bean(ClassName.HELLO)

Comment: I suppose that according to java version and the location of the Processor classes,  you should specify some javac arguments to indicate to the compiler where these are. For Java 8 : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html. IDE does a lot of things for you. Not surprised that it may work straight with it.

Comment: @Eugen It's still not work

Comment: @davidxxx Do you know which parameter shuold added?

Comment: what version of java and spring you are using ? can you publish also class where is declared `public String bean(){` and `public static final String HELLO`

Comment: @Eugen Java version is 1.8.0_112. And it's nothing with spring, I just write `@Bean` for convenience. The class has nothing else. And I can promise there is no user error.

Comment: where is located `HelloWorldMessage.class`  ?

Comment: @Eugen The `HelloWorldMessage` is generated by `filer.createSourceFile`. In standard maven structure, it will be in `target/generated-sources/annotations`.

Comment: Would be helpful to share a full project like structure (w/ `pom.xml`) so that the processor gets executed. Did you try using `enum` instead of `interface`, if the constants are used as such ? I presume it is using the default `classpath` of the IDE or `maven`? Are you getting the same from `mvn` (CLI) and IDE?

Comment: @azbarcea I had given a full minimize sample in the gist.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know this subject so tried to play with it a little bit.
It seems that your example will not work with `javac`, by following the steps you provide, I don't think the processor is called. You could try with some debug parameters to verity it:

1. `-XprintProcessorInfo`: Print information about which annotations a processor is asked to process
2. `-XprintRounds`: Print information about initial and subsequent annotation processing rounds.
3. `-verbose`:Verbose output. This includes information about each class loaded and each source file compiled.

Secondly, it seems like you'll need to provide the processor as a jar, with `/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` in it. I've tried this, it was better but still failed, I think it's because the source file doesn't compile, so the compiler can not retrieve any information about the annotation.(I thought it could by just scanning the source file).

Finally I made it work by moving the use of annotation from `UseHelloWorld` to a `package-info.java` file(or any other files which compile). now the compiler can see that the annotation has been used in a source file, and the processor gets called to generate the `HelloWorldMessage` class which is compiled in the following round. And the class `UseHelloWorld` also compiles.

Note: I've added some `import` and `package` in your files, otherwise it doesn't compile even with the presence of `HelloWorldMessage` class.

I think why it works in Eclipse is because different tools are being used to do the processing. Or maybe you've generated the source file some time and forget to clean it. Hope someone can give a better answer, I'm just sharing my experiments.

---

**Update**

I was stupid by saying we should provide the processor as a jar, obviously a class file is enough (I may have used a wrong classpath). My guess to the updated post is the compiler doesn't handle every case. 
In Eclipse, we see two different errors concerning `@Anno`

1. with `@Anno(HelloWorldMessage.HELLO_WORLD)`: HelloWorldMessage cannot be resolved to a variable
2. with `@Anno(UseHelloWorld.HW)`: The value for annotation attribute Anno.value must be a constant expression

Maybe in the first case the compiler is clever enough to guess the unknown type can be generated by the annotation processor, so it gives a try, and in the second case it treats it as the annotation is incorrectly used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some mistake of create the minimize test case. I have updated my case. Could you try it again, I promise it will work and fail now?

Comment: And I downvote by mistake, when I find it 5 minutes gone. Could you edit your answer so I can revert my downvote.

Comment: @DeanXu I've updated my answer, your example is very interesting and I actually think it's a limitation of the compiler.

Comment: For such constant, compiler will inline it. So the direct and indirect usage should not be different. I have report the bug to oracle.

Comment: @DeanXu I'm not sure inlining will happen here since `HelloWorldMessage` is to be generated. I think at this stage, the compiler only retrieves information about annotation type for processing .

Comment: The boudary will end in 3 hours. I will aware it to your answer for your help. But I can't accept your answer because this problem is not resolved. I have reported the bug to oracle since there is no response. I will try the case in java 9 and 10 later.

Comment: @DeanXu ok, I can't find specifications about this...For me it's a limitation and the compiler should be able to do more work. Please keep me informed if you get any answer, thanks.